# How do i automatically append column names to post data sent to php when grid loads or refreshes?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm new to jqGrid and jquery and i'm learning as fast as i can but i still am a little lost about how to some things like how to append addition information to the post data in jqgrid that gets sent to php.

It would be nice for the php script to know what columns the grid wants when it initially loads or you press the jqgrid refresh/reload button.

I know i can use the postData option: **postData:{name:val,,,},** but i was hoping to just automatically pull the column names from the colModel definitions using this function...

```
    postData: function(){
        colmodel = $('#tab4-grid').jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');
        colarray = '{';
        for (var i in colmodel) {colarray += '"'+colmodel[i].name+'":"'+colmodel[i].name+'",';}
        colarray += '}';
        return colarray;
    },
```

so i would not have to spell them out manually again. However, while the function produces the correct code, it's not getting posted. I can't seem to figure out the problem.  Can someone help please?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing which you have to do is to rewrite

```
postData: function() { ... }
```

to

```
postData: {
    myColumnsName: function() { ... }
}
```

jqGrid already send some standard parameters to the server (`page`, `rows` ,...). With the code above you will add and *additional* parameter with the name `myColumnsName` which you can fill in any way inside of the function body.

You current implementation is **very dirty**. You don't define local variables `colmodel` and `colarray`. Moreover you try to serialize array of strings as object ('{}') and not as array ('[]'). You should not use `for (var i in colmodel)` construction if you enumerate array items `for (var i=0; i<colmodel.length; i++)` is better. Additionally 'colModel' contain some column names ('rn', 'cb', 'subgrid') which you should skip in the enumeration. You can define as `var colNames = [];` and use `colNames.push` to fill it. Then you can use standard `JSON.stringify` method from [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to convert array to the JSON string.